# Is it possible to post multiple data i.e., array of object using POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman

Like

```
[
    {
        "enear": "",
        "inten": 1,
        "sctor": "Eny",
        "topic": "",
        "insight": ""  
    },
    {
        "enear": "",
        "inten": 1,
        "sctor": "Eny",
        "topic": "",
        "insight": ""  
    }
]
```

If possible how to write the nodejs code
This is my code

```
router.post("/post" , async (req,res) => {
    const data = new Model(req.map(r => ({
        enear: r.body.enear,
        inten:r.body.inten,
        sctor: r.body.sctor,
        topic: r.body.topic,
        insight: r.body.insight,
       
    })))
    try{
        const dataToSave = await data.save()
        res.status(200).json(dataToSave)
    }catch(error){
        res.status(400).json({message:error.message})
    }
})
```

Does map works here?

I have tried using map . Is there any possible way please suggest

Comment: Typo. You are trying to treat the [request object](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) like [the request body](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body). You have a request body containing an array of objects, not an array of requests each of which has a single object as its body.

Comment: I also have no idea if you have body parsing middleware set up. The fragment of code you shared doesn't say.

Comment: I also have no idea if the `Model` object accepts an array as its argument since you didn't include that.

Answer (score 0):

You can send an array in the body part and access an array using
`req.body` and use req.body.map here if it satisifies the condition
`Array.isArray(req.body)`

```
router.post("/post" , async (req,res) => {  
   const { body } = req;
   if (Array.isArray(body)) {
       const data = new Model(body.map(r => ({
        enear: r.body.enear,
        inten:r.body.inten,
        sctor: r.body.sctor,
        topic: r.body.topic,
        insight: r.body.insight,
       
    })))
    try{
        const dataToSave = await data.save()
        res.status(200).json(dataToSave)
    }catch(error){
        res.status(400).json({message:error.message})
    }
   }
```